# How to establish SSL Connection using Apache Commons HttpClient?

Tags: ssl, https, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a code that uploads a file via HTTP Post to an IIS Server. My current code only supports http. I tried to follow the example from the apache website (http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html) but I get an error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available

```
    InputStream is = FileUtil.getInputStream("aw.pdf", FileUtil.HDD);
    LogService.info("FileSender#sendFile() Start");

    Protocol easyhttps = new Protocol("https", new SSLConnecionService(), 443);
    Protocol.registerProtocol("https", easyhttps);

    HostConfiguration hc = new HostConfiguration();

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod();
    String[] aw = StringUtil.split("10.191.21.56/myiis7project/", "/");

    try {
        URI uri = new URI("https", "", "10.191.21.56", 443, "/myiis7project/");
        post.setURI(uri);
        hc.setHost(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), easyhttps);
        client.executeMethod(hc, post);
    } catch (URIException e) {
        LogService.info("FileSender#sendFile() URIException: " + e);
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream fileToUpload = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[102400];
        for (int len; (len = is.read(buffer)) != -1;)
            fileToUpload.write(buffer, 0, len);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogService.error("FileSender#sendFile(): " + e);
    }

    ByteArrayPartSource file = new ByteArrayPartSource("aw.pdf", fileToUpload.toByteArray()); 
    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("", "");
    client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    try { 

        // Set chunk 
        post.setContentChunked(false); 
        Part[] part = new Part[] { new FilePart("aw.pdf", file)}; 
        post.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(part, post.getParams())); 

        int statusCode = client.executeMethod(post); 
        LogService.info("FileSender#sendFile() Response Code: " + statusCode);

        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
            LogService.info("FileSender#sendFile() Response Message: " + post.getStatusText());
        }else {
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally { 
        post.releaseConnection();
        try {
            if (is != null) is.close();
            if (fileToUpload != null) fileToUpload.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    LogService.info("FileSender#sendFile() End");
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider Apache HTTP Client 4.x. Version 3 has been discontinued for a long time.

Comment: My device is only limited to java 1.4. So only 3.1 is supported.